# How to generate a monthly report using 1 formula at A2

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I am trying to build a monthly report. How can I write 1 formula at A2 to show Monthly Expense Summary.

I want months to show in a descending order.  (May  April   March   February    January)

Thanks a lot.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vWxcEN4bW-4pt4ZCOhX1VUsT7bPzmUhf9edeNJ-iB-s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY({TEXT(13-TEXT(Data!A2:A, "m"), "000")&
 TEXT(Data!A2:A, "×mmmm"), Data!A2:C}, 
 "select Col3,sum(Col4) where Col4>0 group by Col3 pivot Col1")&"", "^\d+×", ))
```

[image]